# moving source code from TFS git to local git

Tags: git

I have a requirement in which we are currently using git as a version control in TFS and would like to move source code from TFS-Git version control to a local git repository.

Is there a documentation as to how this can be achieved along with complete history of change sets.

Answer (score 1):

Clone the repository like you normally would. That's all you have to do.

Cloning the repository gives you the entire history of the repository.

`git clone --mirror` will mirror the entire repo. You can then add a new remote and push it wherever you want. Note that a mirrored repository is also a bare repository, so you can't work in it like you normally would. If you need to work on a mirrored repo, you can run the following commands:

```
git config --bool core.bare false
git checkout master
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I will try.